# Upload AVAsset to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, avasset

I'm trying to upload a video that the app has as an AVAsset into Firebase Storage. The problem is that I am having problems both converting it to Data or just uploading as a file. As of now I am trying to export and upload its URL, but the app crasher without explanation (the dreaded (llbd)).

```
let uuid: String = UUID().uuidString
            let imagesRef = storageRef.child("\(uuid)")
            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videos[i], presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

        let uploadTask = imagesRef.putFile(from: exporter!.outputURL!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in //app crasher here
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                return
            }

            let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL()

//REST OF CODE
```

Any ideas how to make this process possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant but you have to use it a new way as:

```
imagesRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in  //code })
```

Hope this helps